# How to find the value of the projection of an angle onto a plane?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, plane-geometry, triangulation, collision-detection

Consider a triangle (T) in 3D space of **given** vertices A, B, and C.

A **given** ray (R) (assumed to be in the direction of the x-axis) hits the triangle at one of its vertices - say A.

Let $\theta$ be the angle between vectors AB and AC.

Let $\beta$ be the projection of $\theta$ onto the plane perpendicular to the ray and containing vertex A.

How to find $\beta$ ?

[A show case example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w45ep.png)

Image source: Jing Li, Wencheng Wang,Fast and robust GPU-based point-in-polyhedron determination, Computer-Aided Design, Volume 87, 2017, Pages 20-28,
ISSN 0010-4485, https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cad.2017.02.001.

Comment: One approach is to find AB' and AC' (The projection of AB, and AC respectively) and then find the angle between them. However such approach is computationally expensive there must be a better approach with lesser computations that finds the angle from the original provided information.

Comment: The value of the angle $\theta $ does not suffice for computation of $\beta $.

Comment: @user Vertices A, B, and C coordinates are available.

Comment: If the coordinates of all three points are given the solution can be obtained by elementary means. However in this case one does not need the value of angle $\theta$.